# Firebase doesn't default to index.html

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Trying to deploy my React app on Firebase. The problem is that after I deploy the app and connect to the default "app.web" domain I keep getting "Site Not Found" page. I followed the initial steps and bundled the app with parcelJS.

However adding /index.html at the end resolves my issue.
Connecting to the "firebase.com" domain works as expected without the need of adding "index.html" at the end.

My previous project which I now removed worked seamlessly without such issues.

What causes this behavior? Can I do anything to fix it?

Contents of firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rewrites are correct for a single page app. it maybe an issue related to your browser cache, try another browser or clear your one with `Ctrl F5`.

If issues persist, you should look at your react app and double-check any router paths and that you do have an existing public folder in the root with your index.html and your react app setup correctly.

As a last resort incase something severe maybe broken, you can create a new project folder and init your Firebase project into it and copy your react src folder over and rebuild your public folder, firebase.json, etc and redeploy with `firebase deploy --only hosting`